# How do I trigger my jQuery script on resize event

Tags: jquery, navigation, responsive-design

I have a jQuery script that reorganizes my menu into a select form element, it works fine.

I want to trigger it on the .resize() event but I can´t get it to work. How do I this?

```
 $(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        /* Get the window's width, and check whether it is narrower than 580 pixels */
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth <= 580) {

            /* Clone our navigation */
            var mainNavigation = $('nav.main-navigation').clone();

            /* Replace unordered list with a "select" element to be populated with options, and create a variable to select our new empty option menu */
            $('nav.main-navigation').html('<select class="menu"></select>');
            var selectMenu = $('select.menu');

            /* Navigate our nav clone for information needed to populate options */
            $(mainNavigation).children('ul').children('li').each(function () {

                /* Get top-level link and text */
                var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
                var text = $(this).children('a').text();

                /* Append this option to our "select" */
                $(selectMenu).append('<option value="' + href + '">' + text + '</option>');

                /* Check for "children" and navigate for more options if they exist */
                if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
                    $(this).children('ul').children('li').each(function () {

                        /* Get child-level link and text */
                        var href2 = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
                        var text2 = $(this).children('a').text();

                        /* Append this option to our "select" */
                        $(selectMenu).append('<option value="' + href2 + '">--- ' + text2 + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });

        }

        /* When our select menu is changed, change the window location to match the value of the selected option. */
        $(selectMenu).change(function () {
            location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: first you start off by posting relevant code ... and also, you're not changing it dynamically ... if you down-size and then up-size again, the select form is prevailing (which I believe it shouldn't be happening)

Comment: to correct the error I just mentioned you need an else statement reverting the actions inside the main if condition ... that code is just saying that if you get below 580px in width it changes to select menu and it remais that way until you reload your page.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the event handler binding, so the issue is assumedly in the code you've said works correctly. Can you explain exactly what is wrong with the code (what it does, why that's incorrect, what it should be doing instead) rather than just saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks henser, you are right. But how do I revert it from selcet menu to a list menu?

Comment: Anthony Grist: What I mean is that the code works fine when I surf in to the site with a mobile device, without the resize event but it didn´t work when I just downsized the window. I hade to update the page to get the select menu. Now when I have this code the select menu becomes blank, and as henser mention it stays that way when I upsize the window and have to reload the page to get the list menu. 
Excuse my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this on for `resize!`

```
$("#div").resize(function(e){
   // do something when #div element resize
});
```